# MySQL Database errors with deadlock when restoring backup

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, percona, percona-xtradb-cluster

we recently wanted to switch from a single MariaDB server to a replicated Percona XtraDB instance. For this purpose I set up an XtraDB cluster in our kubernetes cluster with 7 nodes distributed across four geographical zones (US, EU, India, AP).

I then wanted to import one of our backups from our old database into the new cluster.
The .sql file for that table is 2.1GB big and consists of roughly 4.5 Million rows.
I tried importing it using

```bash
mysql -h mysql-prod -u root -p my_database < backup_file.sql
```

This will prompt me for a password, begin running and insert rows. However, after some time, I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1213 (40001) at line 93582: Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

The given line is a regular part of an INSERT INTO statement that inserts the data into the database.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with xtradb or an issue with my configuration of it.
Maybe someone knows whats wrong?